# Permutation of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a (3x1) list

```
testL= [(('str1', 'str2', 'str3'), 'otherStr1'), (('str1', 'str2', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), (('str1', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), (('str2', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1')]
```

I want to have a combination such

```
('str1', 'otherStr1')
('str2', 'otherStr1')
('str3', 'otherStr1')

('str1', 'otherStr1')
('str2', 'otherStr1')
('str4', 'otherStr1')

('str1', 'otherStr1')
('str3', 'otherStr1')
('str4', 'otherStr1')

('str2', 'otherStr1')
('str3', 'otherStr1')
('str4', 'otherStr1')
```

I have tried `itertools` functions. Eg `prod = list(itertools.product(testL, repeat=1)) print('prod:', prod)`

```
[((('str1', 'str2', 'str3'), 'otherStr1'),), ((('str1', 'str2', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'),), ((('str1', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'),), ((('str2', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'),)]
```

How can I get desired output?

Comment: Your output is not a valid Python data structure. Are you expecting a flat list or a nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using itertools.product() with your data structure is tricky because of the nested tuples.  Also, it's really not worth pulling out product() for just two dimensional data.
2. Your input is not very clearly defined.  I am going to assume that you meant to provide the following input.  Note that you had four copies of 'otherStr1'.  I am pretty sure you want the otherStr from the same tuple from which you are taking the smaller strings.  My version shows the distinction:

```python
testL= [(('str1', 'str2', 'str3'), 'otherStr1'), (('str1', 'str2', 'str4'), 'otherStr2'), (('str1', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr3'), (('str2', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr4')]
```

3. Your desired output is also not clearly defined.  Do you want flat or nested output?  My program provides both.

Solution:

```python
flat, nested = [], []  # Take your pick!
for seq, other in testL:
    items = [(x, other) for x in seq]
    flat.extend(items)
    nested.append(items)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The nested list was very usefull for me. I am also asking me, how can I access indivudial elements in that list?

Answer (score 1):

With built-in `zip()` function:

```
testL= [ (('str1', 'str2', 'str3'), 'otherStr1'), (('str1', 'str2', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), 
         (('str1', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), (('str2', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1')
]
result = [tuple(zip(t[0], [t[1]] * len(t[0]))) for t in testL]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[(('str1', 'otherStr1'), ('str2', 'otherStr1'), ('str3', 'otherStr1')), (('str1', 'otherStr1'), ('str2', 'otherStr1'), ('str4', 'otherStr1')), (('str1', 'otherStr1'), ('str3', 'otherStr1'), ('str4', 'otherStr1')), (('str2', 'otherStr1'), ('str3', 'otherStr1'), ('str4', 'otherStr1'))]
```

Comment: Hm, OP's desired output looks like a flat list, not a nested list. Not sure about that, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, as for the OP's "output": it looks like text content (not flat list nor nested list); so it's considered as demonstration structure

Answer (score 0):

You don't need itertools for this at all:

```
In [4]: [(s, item[1]) for item in testL for s in item[0]]
Out[4]:
[('str1', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str2', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str3', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str1', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str2', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str4', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str1', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str3', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str4', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str2', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str3', 'otherStr1'),
 ('str4', 'otherStr1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach where there can be many string and it will give combination with each one ,

```
testL= [(('str1', 'str2', 'str3'), 'otherStr14','other_','other_other','other_other_other'), (('str1', 'str2', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), (('str1', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1'), (('str2', 'str3', 'str4'), 'otherStr1')]

import itertools
for i in testL:
    final_output=[]
    sub_ = []
    other_ = []
    for k in i:


        if not isinstance(k,tuple):
            sub_.append(k)
        else:

            other_.extend(list(k))

    for mk in itertools.product(sub_,other_):
        print(list(mk))
```

output:

```
['otherStr14', 'str1']
['otherStr14', 'str2']
['otherStr14', 'str3']
['other_', 'str1']
['other_', 'str2']
['other_', 'str3']
['other_other', 'str1']
['other_other', 'str2']
['other_other', 'str3']
['other_other_other', 'str1']
['other_other_other', 'str2']
['other_other_other', 'str3']
['otherStr1', 'str1']
['otherStr1', 'str2']
['otherStr1', 'str4']
['otherStr1', 'str1']
['otherStr1', 'str3']
['otherStr1', 'str4']
['otherStr1', 'str2']
['otherStr1', 'str3']
['otherStr1', 'str4']
```